# Can't use right mouse click to copy contact details in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

If I want to copy a number or the email address of a contact the context menu option to copy doesn't show up. On a computer of a colleague, it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: This question needs a lot of clarity. You might try reinstalling Office. Uninstall, restart, install Office and patch.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to copy on Outlook for web or Outlook desktop client?

If on Outlook client, is the copy option shown in the figure below not shown up or other option?
[image]

If it is the copy option in the above figure, agree with John, uninstalling and reloading is really a good way. As a supplement, considering the Outlook client itself may be damaged. It is recommended that you try to [fix the Office application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to check if there're any differences.

If the above is not your case, please provide more information about the copy option, such as screenshots.(In order to avoid the disclosure of your privacy, please remember to hide your personal information)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, yes I was referring to the option you showed in the screenshot. Since the user didn't call back, it seems that a reboot helped. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I noticed that you solved the problem after restarting. Would you mind writing this solution as an answer and marking it as the answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.